# How do I fix "Cannot find name 'IResponse'" in Apollo Client

Tags: node.js, typescript, apollo-client

Here's the full set of errors:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/apollo-client/transport/afterware.d.ts:3:15         
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'IResponse'.                                             
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/apollo-client/transport/networkInterface.d.ts:44:15 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'IResponse'.                                             
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules/apollo-client/transport/networkInterface.d.ts:56:77 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'IResponse'.
```

I can fix all of these errors by modifying those two Apollo Client files but that's not a sustainable solution.

I already have npm installed `@types/isomorphic-fetch` and `@types/node` as recommended by this thread:  https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/207 and I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is fixed in the latest version of apollo.

Upgrade `apollo-client` to `0.10.0`

Upgrade `react-apollo` to `0.13.1` (just released)